# Choosing an option from context menu in windows browser (VBA)

Tags: vba, contextmenu, explorer

I have a folder with thousands of files within hundreds of sub-folders. In each instance I need to right click on a file and select an option from the context menu. I would like to do it within VBA.

I have the ability (and code) to list all file names, but not sure of the next step.

Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: If you have all your files on a sheet and want to mimic the right-click of the windows explorer then it would seem that you want to look into `Worksheet_BeforeRightClick`.

Comment: Thanks @ralph. Maybe I am not looking in the right place, but it seems to me that Worksheet_BeforeRightClick lets me pick the context menu within the spreadsheet. I am actually looking for the menu in a windows explorer. As an example, when I right click on a file name in explorer I get the option "convert to pdf".

Comment: VBA works only within Microsoft Office: Excel, Word, Outlook, etc. You cannot use it to control the windows explorer.

Comment: You should use AutoIt, not vba

Comment: I am in a (secure) corporate environment - I don't have the ability to install AutoIt. Or run powershell for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) is a Visual Basic engine that can run within host applications such as the Office applications Word, Excel.

You can read more information about VBA here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications

You are most likely better served using a different context and language (for instance VbScript, PowerShell or common managed languages VB.NET or C# to name some) to reach your goal.

Comment: Thank you Maarten. I do have some experience with VBA  - I've for example traversed and changed end of line character in hundreds of files within many folders/subfolders (from unix to windows). I am at best a hobby programmer within a corporate environment where I don't have flexibility to play with most programming environments. Maybe I'll try VbScript.

Comment: I didn't get the time to research this much, but have spent some time reading now. It seems that vbscript is a subset of VBA. Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970436.aspx
The article starts with: 
Because VBScript is a subset of Visual Basic for Applications, many of the familiar features of Visual Basic for Applications are supported.

Comment: The point is that VBA, the name already implies this, is an -embedded- version of VB, in this case (but not limited to being) hosted in Excel or Word. In your case I read that you want to run code in a folder, i.e. -not embedded-. In that case VBScript is your better option. Sure VBScript is a subset of VBA but the context is completely different where the first is able to run independent an the second is depending on the host (Word, Excel in this case). VBScript however is powerful enough to perform most of the needed tasks in its context.

Comment: I need to run code that "modifies" a folder (technically files inside the folder) - does not necessarily have to sit inside the folder. From that perspective (for the benefit of future readers of this question), vbscript will not make the task any easier than VBA.

Comment: With the exception that you do need a host such as Word or Excel to run your VB(A) task where with vbscript you can do it everywhere you like without additional host applications.